# Не срабатывает параметр transition | JS

Tags: javascript, css, анимация, transition

Написал диву стиль `transition: width 1s ease-in-out;`
Когда через **панель инструментов** меняю ширину с 280px на 0, то все работает плавно. **НО**, если я делаю то же самое через js:
`element.style.width = 0`, то див **мгновенно** схлопывается. **Что делать?**

Answer (score 0):

А как именно Вы делаете через js? Если просто в коде пишете `element.style.width = 0`, то, разумеется, никакой плавности не будет. Плавное изменение может происходить только по какому-то событию (например, клику) либо по таймауту:

```js
document.getElementById('div').onclick = function() {
    this.style.width = 0;
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 280px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">Кликни</div>
```

```js
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('div').style.width = 0; },2000)
```

```css
div {
  width: 280px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">Подожди пару секунд</div>
```

Comment: Происходит по клику.

Comment: @SireIMPACTUS, ну вот я Вам привёл пример, как по клику надо делать, чтобы было плавно

Comment: у меня dom формируется динамически, так что проблема не в ожидании. Когда я нажимаю на див, все функции, которые должны были работать, работают, включая изменения ширины, НО transition его словно не видит. Думаю, может проблема в том, что не туда вешаю свойство, поэтому повесил на все элементы соседние и родительские, итог тот же.